# Using package name instead of nested folders for non-source files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package

In Java projects in Eclipse, source folders can be represented by package names:

- com.example.foo.bar

Non-source folders are shown as a folder hierarchy:

- com

  - example

    - foo

      - bar

Is is possible to use "package" names representation for non-source folders without adding them to the classpath?